# Map Data From Array To ListView

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I have an array of objects that I want to display in a ListView. Not all data in each object will be displayed. What is the best way of doing this considering I will want to filter which records are displayed (depending on a status flag) and easy way to update columns in the listview on the fly.

The data in the array will look something like (simplified). It doesn't have to be an array though. If there is a better option then that's fine.

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Text1;
    public string Text2;
    public string Text3;
    public int Status;
}
```

There will be other methods and properties in the class but this is what will be displayed.

Also, I will need to update this data/listview from a worker thread. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: WPF? WinForms? ASP.Net? Silverlight? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
listView1.Items.AddRange
    (
        (
            from c in classList
            where c.Status = 1
            select new ListViewItem(c.Text1 + c.Text2, c.Text3)
        ).ToArray()
    );
```

Comment: Yes, except that `class` is a keyword.

Comment: ListView doesn't have a DataSource member.

Comment: @Jonnster: Yes it does. Check [ListView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx)

Comment: I'm not using the web control. I am using the windows forms control. So no it doesn't. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks but that won't build. The error is Error 1 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type MyListClass'.  'Where' not found.

Comment: Error 1 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem>' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem[]'

Comment: The above error is the one I am getting now. To be honest, having an answer that just says "try this" with no explanation of the code, etc is not that helpful. Can anyone else please help.

Comment: @Jonnster: And by the way, if you need to understand the provided code then you need to ask in a nice way ..